# How to mint nft with ERC721A using tokenuri or uri (string) as in URI-Storage?

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, mint

I want to mint NFT using ERC721A but I cant use the TokenURI.

```
function prizeDistribution(uint256 jackPotId)
    external
    payable
    override
    returns(uint256)
    {
        require(_dateTime._now() >= _jackPots[jackPotId]._endTime ,
        "Time has not passed enough for this JackPot");
        require(_dateTime.get15DaysSeconds() >= _jackPots[jackPotId]._endTime,"15 Days have not passed for this jackpot");
        //check time after endTime ,that has it been 15 days ?
        
        address[] memory participants = this.getParticipantAddresses(jackPotId);
        //SideNote to call another implemented external function, use this keyword
        //then make a function in which the participants list is passed
        
        address winner =  this.calculateRandomWinnerFromList(participants,jackPotId);
        //generate a single random number from the list of participants length
        //return that address and rest of the list excluding that winner
        
        IERC20(0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138).transfer(winner,_jackPots[jackPotId]._prizePool);
        _jackPots[jackPotId]._prizePool = 0;
        

        /*
        I want to use ERC721A and batch mint N amount of participants 
        that took part and transfer nfts to them
        */

        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Hey @Murtaza. Welcome to ETH StackExchange. Could you please provide a code snippet of what you are trying to do so that the context becomes clearer to us and we could help you better?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/51644/ahmed-ihsan-tawfeeq 
Added the Code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, ERC721A only allows you to batch mint NFT IDs to a single recipient address. If you have multiple recipients, then you will have to use a for loop and call `_safeMint` to each and every recipient address. And by doing so, you lose any batch mint advantages offered by ERC721A.

Note: using for loops in Solidity is heavily discouraged due to unexpected gas costs and the possibility of exceeding the max block gas limit.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/51644/ahmed-ihsan-tawfeeq 

Ok, So does ERC1155 provides the following functionality:
1) Send NFT to multiple Addresses
2) Use Stroage-URI ?

Comment: @SyedMurtazaAliShah No, there's nothing in the ERC1155 specification that suggests that it does.
If you still want to mint to multiple participants, you will most-likely need to write a `bulkMint` function that takes `address[] calldata accounts` as input, and then use  a for loop to mint one NFT per each account in `accounts`. This is better, since here you will always be able to control the number of iterations of the for loop by adjusting the input array size.

Comment: Though, you will probably need to adjust the entire list of participants into smaller input chunks and call `bulkMint` on each chunk at a time.