# I want mint N-number of NFT's to N-number of people using ERC1155

Tags: nft, erc-1155, mint, batch

E.G: 1-NFT minted sent to 1-person, But in a broader perspective. e.g: 100 NFT's to 100 people, In the same function using ERC1155. I want to mint and transfer those 100 nfts in the same function. To send multiple nfts to multiple addresses.

Comment: You can do that , you need to write a new function that call mint and transfer N-Time :/?  You need to check how much that cost and maybe call that function multiple time to avoid out of gas or block limit

Comment: Thank You, Can you answer this question as well https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/128147/how-to-mint-nft-with-erc721a-using-tokenuri-or-uri-string-as-in-uri-storage/128201#128201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function receives and array of target addresses, an array of ids and an array of amounts. It should work well in your erc1155 contract.

```
function massMint(address[] memory _to, uint256[] memory _ids, uint256[] memory _amounts)
    external
    onlyOwner
{
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _to.length; ++i) {
        _mint(_to[i], _ids[i], _amounts[i], "");
    }
}
```